# Connection between different Web-Services? (eg: Twitter-Feeds on Facebook)

Tags: web-services, connection, data-transfer

does anybody know agood way in granting a connection from one service to another, so that both services benefits fromeach other?

I would like to have an easy but never the less safe way to do a connection between my server and another server, but I don't know how to do that.

It should be ...
easy, so that neither the user nor the service providers have to waste alot of time
traffic effecient, so that traffic is not wasted and conenction is fast
encrypted, so that no person in between can use the transmitted data
and it should be an open and flexible standard, so that there could be more connections to other services (with my server in the middle of this star connection and no connection in between all providers) and that I don't have to pay a fee ;).

the example in the title is something I think about, because when you have a twitter account you somehow connect facebook to your account and facebook can show your twitterfeeds on your account.
but I don't want a provider to gather a lot of information beside the really important one that the user want to transmit. so I don't want the provide to get the username of my user and I don't really need to know how my user is named there.
It's like a post-office box. you just have to know where to put your letter, but you don't need to know the box owner's name.
and I don't want the mail-carrier to know what he is delivering, so it should be encrypted.

every clue how to do that would be fine, because I don't know anything about this :)

thank you in advance, Andreas

Comment: Hi,

I found SOAP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP as a way to communicate, but as far as I understand there is no specific transport mentioned besides beeing http. But I want it to be encrpyted and that neither side can does know any information of the user data of the opposite server. but the transported data should be stilltranpostered and stored under the right receiver-name.

Andreas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is [OAuth](http://oauth.net/), check out the "Getting Started" guide to learn all about it

And the [wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)

Comment: Hi, I found SOAP and you posted OAuth, and I think there are some other choices. But how do they compare to each other?

Comment: SOAP is an protocol for exchanging structured information using XML messages

OAuth is a security token exchange protocol to allow foreign access to private resources. OAuth uses HTTP like messages to request a token. It does not actually carry useful data, that is dependent on the data service. e.g Twitter API uses OAuth to authenticate and XML via a REST interface.   

OAuth will allow you to do "granting a connection from one service to another, so that both services benefits from each other"